# Is there a way to _somehow_ use an enum value to pass a method call as a generic parameter of that method?

Tags: c#, generics, enums

(The question might not make enough sense. It was hard to write it. Feel free to update it if you can make it more clear.)

I have an enum:

```
public enum nodeTypes 
{ 
    Part = 1, 
    SelectListValue, 
    MultiSelectListValue, 
    RepeatingPart,
    ...
}
```

And a method with a switch case:

```
switch (type)
{
    case nodeTypes.SelectListValue:
        GenerateSubNode<SelectListValue>(parent, root, depth, true);
        break;
    case nodeTypes.MultiSelectListValue:
        GenerateSubNode<MultiSelectListValue>(parent, root, depth, true);
        break;
    case nodeTypes.Part:
        GenerateSubNode<Part>(parent, root, depth, true);
        break;
    case ....
 }
```

And another method:

```
private void GenerateSubNode<ComponentType>(Container parent, ZForm root, int depth, bool isContainer) where ComponentType : Component, new()
{
    ...
    var c = new ComponentType();
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to write that switch case statement as a 1 liner? It feels like repetitive code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you could try something like WRONG:

```
    List<ComponentType> types = new List { SelectListValue, MultiSelectValue,...}
    ....
    CompenentType type = types[(int)type];
    GenerateSubNode<type>(parent, root,depth, true);
```

Or you could this with the factory pattern.

Edit after good comments :

```
class VehiculeCreation
{ public static List<Type> vehicules = new List<Type> { typeof(Car), typeof(motor) };
enum Vehicule 
{
    Car = 0,
    Motor = 1,
};


static void Main()
{
    vehicule cars = GenerateVehicules((int)Vehicule.Car);
    vehicule motors = GenerateVehicules((int)Vehicule.Motor);
    cars.print();
    motors.print();

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public abstract class vehicule
{
    public abstract void print();
}

public class Car : vehicule
{
    public override void print() {Console.WriteLine("I am a car");}
}

public class motor : vehicule
{
    public override void print() { Console.WriteLine("I am a motor"); }
}

public static vehicule GenerateVehicules(int index)
{
    return (vehicule)System.Activator.CreateInstance(vehicules[index]);
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think you can list `Type`s and pass them as generic parameters like that.

Comment: @BoltClock, Euphoric : deserves the down vote, but I got a working solution now :-)

Comment: k, I had a feeling generics was a way to go

Comment: OP is also doing some stuff with the arguments too, so just calling Activator.CreateInstance is not enough..

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with reflection as well:

```
typeof( ClassWhereGenerateSubNodeMethodIs ) //alternativly, this.GetType()
   .GetMethod( "GenerateSubNode" )
   .MakeGenericMethod( Type.GetType( "namespace.where.type.classes.are." + type.ToString() ) )
   .Invoke( this, new object[ ] { parent, root, depth, true} );
```

`this` that is passed to `Invoke` is the instance on witch `GenerateSubNode` is called, if `GenerateSubNode` was static, you'd pass in null here.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
Dictionary<nodeTypes, Action<Container, ZForm, int, bool>> generateActions = new Dictionary<nodeTypes, Action<Container, ZForm, int, bool>>
{ 
  {nodeTypes.SelectListValue, GenerateSubNode<SelectListValue> },
  {nodeTypes.MultiSelectListValue, GenerateSubNode<MultiSelectListValue> },
  // .. so on
}
```

Then use it:

```
generateActions[type](parent, root, depth, true);
// todo: does action exist? validation
```